# Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working Google Cloud Functions GCF

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, cors, google-cloud-functions

I feel like a newbie here but I'm trying to run a simple AJAX request from a browser to access a GCF and Chrome is reporting:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   https://us-central1-bustling-opus-830.cloudfunctions.net/Authenticate.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'https://beast.reachboarding.com.au' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

I've got a function called Authenticate (as shown above) that's using a bucket called:

```
bustling-opus-830.appspot.com
```

I've used gsutil to set CORS using the following JSON file:

```
[{
    "origin": ["https://beast.localdev.com.au","*"],
    "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"],
    "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"],
    "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
}]
```

With the following command:

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://bustling-opus-830.appspot.com/
```

And then get the following output from the corresponding get command:

```
gsutil cors get gs://bustling-opus-830.appspot.com/

[{"maxAgeSeconds": 3600, "method": ["GET", "HEAD", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"], "origin": ["https://beast.localdev.com.au", "*"], "responseHeader": ["Content-Type"]}]
```

I'm using the default example code that's provided when you create a new function as stated below:

```
/**
 * Responds to any HTTP request that can provide a "message" field in the body.
 *
 * @param {!Object} req Cloud Function request context.
 * @param {!Object} res Cloud Function response context.
 */
exports.helloWorld = function helloWorld(req, res) {
    // Example input: {"message": "Hello!"}
    if (req.body.message === undefined) {
        // This is an error case, as "message" is required.
        res.status(200).send('No message defined!');
    } else {
        // Everything is okay.
        console.log(req.body.message);
        res.status(200).send(req.body.message);
    }
};
```

And a simple HTML with the following Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "https://us-central1-bustling-opus-830.cloudfunctions.net/Authenticate",
    type: "POST",
    data: {
        message: 'Testing'
    },
    dataType: 'json', 
    success: function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status) {
        console.log(xhr);
    }
});
```

Which is causing the error.

In my DEV console I can see the network request go through. Here are the HTTP Response Headers I'm getting are:

```
cache-control:private
content-encoding:gzip
content-length:27
content-type:text/html; charset=utf-8
date:Wed, 08 Feb 2017 03:45:50 GMT
etag:W/"7-274e639a"
function-execution-id:azc1zqfb1tq8
server:Google Frontend
status:200
vary:Accept-Encoding
x-cloud-trace-context:70e08d634a9644c32530326de0471a64;o=1
x-cloud-trace-context:70e08d634a9644c32530326de0471a64
x-powered-by:Express
```

I would have expected to see the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header within the Response Headers to indicate that it was allowing * but I'm definitely not seeing it.

The crazy thing though is that when I look at the Network item and click on Response I get:

```
Testing
```

Which suggests that all things being equal, it ACTUALLY ran!

I apologise if this has been answered before but I've searched for as many different keywords and nothing seems to have solved my problem. I thought a fresh pair of eyes on the issue (and some decent expertise) would help.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the correct gsutil command `gsutil cors set cors.json gs://bustling-opus-830`, or you already sure that `gsutil cors set cors.json gs://bustling-opus-830.appspot.com/` should achieve the same thing? I ask because the docs at https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/cross-origin#Configuring-CORS-on-a-Bucket just use the unqualified form `gsutil cors set cors-json-file.json gs://example`

Comment: I believe the two commands are syntactically the same. The only difference I see is the name of the JSON file. I used cors.json where as the example has cors-json-file.json. Is that what you mean?

Comment: No, I just meant `gs://bustling-opus-830.appspot.com/` vs `gs://bustling-opus-830`

Comment: Ahh got you. I just tried without the .appspot.com and get a "NotFoundException: 404" message. I then tried gsutil cors get gs://bustling-opus-830 and get "BucketNotFoundException: 404 gs://bustling-opus-830 bucket does not exist." so I'm assuming what Google docs have is just a reference to the bucket rather than the absolute path. Thanks for your help so far. Any other thoughts? Have you successfully been able to post via AJAX to a GCF?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Your foreground (HTTP) Google Cloud Function needs to set the appropriate CORS headers in the responses to the AJAX client requests. The request and response parameters of [HTTP Functions](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http) have equivalent properties to the corresponding ExpressJS objects which can be used to set the CORS headers and respond to preflight requests as needed.

For example:

```
exports.Authenticate = function Authenticate (req, res) {
    //set JSON content type and CORS headers for the response
    res.header('Content-Type','application/json');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');

    //respond to CORS preflight requests
    if (req.method == 'OPTIONS') {
        res.status(204).send('');
    }

    //continue function ...

};
```

The headers and logic above should be modified to reflect the particular needs of your service but should hopefully help you get started.

Comment: Ryan you dead set legend! I can't believe this is how STUPIDLY simple it was. I added the headers and hit refresh and it instantly performed as expected. THANK YOU so much!

Comment: You are my savior. I spent all day trying to figure this out and this was the only thing that fixed it.

Answer (score 9):

You can also use the `cors` package to fix this, as recommended by Google. In fact, they also use this in their own sample codes. Check this [example](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/time-server/functions/index.js).
This is the code -

```
const cors = require('cors')({
    origin: true,
});

//Your code here

//Use the following function instead of just res.send. return keyword is not compulsory here
return cors(req, res, () => {
    res.send();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are still interested in an answer, I actually wrote a blog post on how to handle that with Express middleware: https://mhaligowski.github.io/blog/2017/03/10/cors-in-cloud-functions.html.

Comment: This link appears to be broken now.