# Stripe checkout failing to load from firebase cloud function (Fixed)

Tags: node.js, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

Edit: Update on how I got it working at bottom.
I have a cloud function which creates a stripe checkout session when it is called from my React application.
When it is called I get the following error in the debugger: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED

Here is the cloud function:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const cors = require('cors');

const stripe = require('stripe')((private key removed for this question))

app.use(cors());

exports.createCheckoutSession = functions.https.onRequest(async (req, res) => {
        const session = await stripe.checkout.sessions.create({
            payment_method_types: ['card'],
            line_items: [
                {
                    price_data: {
                        currency: 'usd',
                        product_data: {
                            name: 'T-shirt',
                        },
                        unit_amount: 2000,
                    },
                    quantity: 1,
                },
            ],
            mode: 'payment',
            success_url: 'https://example.com/success.html',
            cancel_url: 'https://example.com/cancel.html',
        });

        res.json({id: session.id});
    });

    app.listen(4242, () => console.log(`Listening on port ${4242}!`));
```

I believe the cloud function is working correctly as when I run:

```
curl -X POST -is "https://us-central1-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/createCheckoutSession" -d ""
```

I get a success message.

And here is where it is called on the front-end:

```
    const response = await fetch("https://us-central1-project-name.cloudfunctions.net/createCheckoutSession", {
           method: "POST",
        });

        const session = await response.json();

        // When the customer clicks on the button, redirect them to Checkout.
        const result = await stripe.redirectToCheckout({
            sessionId: session.id,
        });

        if (result.error) {
            // If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
            // error, display the localized error message to your customer
            // using `result.error.message`.
            alert(result.error.message);
        }
    };
```

I am getting the error on the fetch call.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update:
I managed to get it to work by referencing this post:
[Access-Control-Allow-Origin not working Google Cloud Functions GCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42140247/access-control-allow-origin-not-working-google-cloud-functions-gcf)

The issue was with CORS. I needed to add in these headers to the function method:

```
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST');
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type');
    res.set('Access-Control-Max-Age', '3600');
```

Comment: Are you seeing anything on your Firebase logs? Have you checked your Stripe dashboard and made sure those requests are succeeding?

Comment: I just checked both firebase and stripe and the requests are succeeding on both.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create something called a **paymentIntent** from backend  and then pass the **paymentIntent Id** to your frontend, here is an example `const stripe = require('stripe')('sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc'); const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({ amount: 2000, currency: 'usd', payment_method_types: ['card'], });` why are you using a cloud function using react and simple nodes app  will be a lot better (**because you will need to set up webhooks for stripe to hit your api for certain transaction**) and safer too, I have integrated stripe this way into my react app and it works fine I can share some code snippets, the authentication and all the important stuff will be done in your nodejs app or what ever server-side you are using the front end will only handle the results and you will be able to show errors, add retry logic etc
[React Stripe Doc](https://stripe.com/docs/stripe-js/react)

Comment: From what I have seen using some sort of back end to handle the payment logic was more secure.

Comment: It will be backend, you will be sending your data to the backend to handle the frontend wont reveal anything it is in their doc, so basically you send the data to the backend apply all operations like price check, if the user has a saved card etc and then send the result back to the frontend it is neat and you can add some retry logic if the payment fails and so on

Comment: With this method, what would you deploy the node.js backend on? Would it not need to be constantly running, therefore needing to be deployed on a cloud function?